# How to improve the output of fine tuned Open Llama 7b model for text generation?

Tags: large-language-model, fine-tuning, llama-index, peft

I am trying to fine tune a openllama model with huggingface's peft and lora. I fine tuned the model on a specific dataset. However, the output from the `model.generate()` is very poor for the given input. When I give a whole sentence form the dataset then it generates related texts, otherwise it is not. Are there any way to improve it?